# KO / JS: Refreshing an array by only pushing new values and keeping existing ones

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

I have a `getTasks` function that returns a list of tasks:

```
$.getJSON("http://todo/actions/", function(data) {
    self.tasks([]); // empty before refresh
    ko.utils.arrayMap(data, function(task) {
        return self.tasks.unshift(new Task.Model(task));
    });
});
```

I also have a refresh button connected to this function that refreshes the list. But before I could run the refresh button I had to empty the observable array, so there wouldn't be any duplicates.

This all works fine, but inside my view, the `foreach` binding includes both `afterAdd` and `beforeRemove` callbacks, which mess things up visually. Whenever I hit the refresh button, the whole list fades out while the new list fades in.

Is there a way to refresh that array to only add new values to it and keep existing ones?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`ko.mapping`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) and specify the `key` property to define how knockout should detect an existing item's being updated vs. a new item's being added.

Have a look at `ko.mapping.fromJS` and how the docs define the `key` property.

Comment: I'll accept your answer once I get around this part of the project again and get it working. Hope it doesn't take another year. :)

Comment: @Norbert: No worries. if it helps, I wrote a simple [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QQdL2/) a while ago that I refer to that does this sort of thing. The items add/remove/update, but you can see (from the timestamp) when they're actually created.